# Conditional validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have in my model these two fields - **recurring_interval** and **recurring_time** - where I need to validate, that these two fields will be set up both or none of them.

If user will want to set up recurring, he will need to set up both these columns. But if he doesn't, he will leave these columns empty.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom validation:

```
class MyModel
  ...
  validate :verify_recurring_stuff
  ..

  private
  def verify_recurring_stuff
    ri = self.recurring_interval
    rt = self.recurring_time

    if ri.blank? != rt.blank?
      self.errors.add(:base, 'Your error message')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried it but even if I set up only one value, the form is sent out, no error message displayed.

Comment: Share your form and controller action.

Comment: Hi Cortex, I made it partially work, but there is one issue - when I sent the form, the controller receive `"recurring_time(1i)"=>"1", "recurring_time(2i)"=>"1", "recurring_time(3i)"=>"1", "recurring_time(4i)"=>"", "recurring_time(5i)"=>""}`, which means the validation always yell an error - how to validate only hours and minutes?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with Recurring_validator
end

class RecurringValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.recurring_interval.blank? != record.recurring_time.blank?
      record.errors[:base] << "Error message" 
    end
  end
end
```

The advantage of this approach is, you can use the validator class for other models too.